# Hyper-parameter tuning when you don't have an access to the test data

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameters

I'm building models for SQUAD (Stanford Question Answering) dataset (https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer).  Stanford doesn't release its test set. It only provides us with training and dev dataset.

Here is my question:

When I tune hyper-parameters of different models, I tuned them on "dev" data given by Stanford. However, we treated "dev" set as "test" set since we didn't have an access to the real "testing" data. We pick only 1 model to submit among different models based on the performance on "dev" dataset.

so I was wondering if I should have separated the training set further into train and dev, and tuned the hyperparams on a newly separated dev set, not the dev set given by Stanford, since we are using "dev" set as "test" set. 
​
Did I somehow cheat? Do I need to create another "dev" data from existing train data, splitting it further, and tune the hyperparams there, and check the perf number on given "dev" set?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's completely fine (assuming you have enough data) to split the training set further into new (smaller) train and test, use the dev set to tune hyper-parameters and evaluate performance on test set.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by cross validation. It will do all this for you. The advantage here is suppose you want the training set to be splitted into 10 sets. It will take 9 set as training and one set for validation. And this way it will run 10 times and then it takes the average of best 3 (if you give best of 3 set parameter).